# How to manually convert an integer into an IP address in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, ip-address

Can anyone assist me in manually converting an integer into an IP address?

I understand the concept, but I am struggling to figure out the process; the number 631271850, has an IP address of '37.160.113.170'.

I know that an IP address is made up of four octets and the solution I have to manually converting an IP address into a number is:

```
def ip_to_num(ip_address)
  array = ip_address.split('.').map(&:to_i)
  ((array[0] * 2**24) + (array[1] * 2**16) + (array[2] * 2**8) + (array[3]))
end
```

To do the reverse is puzzling me. How do I convert it back?

Comment: What are the backslashes doing in there? `2**2` is the correct notation.

Comment: Why don't you use the existing classes for this? Ruby comes with https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/index.html and there's https://github.com/dspinhirne/netaddr-rb.

Comment: Newby here, so excuse my errors.

Comment: You are simply converting from decimal representation (base-10) to a representation in base-256, nothing more. An IPv4 address is a 32 bit number written as 4 "digits" in base-256.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An IP is just a 32-bit integer representing a 4-byte array:

```
[631271850].pack('N').unpack('CCCC').join('.')
=> "37.160.113.170"
```

Just for fun, another way to convert IP to int:

```
"37.160.113.170".split(".").map(&:to_i).pack('CCCC').unpack('N')[0]
=> 631271850
```

Answer (score 3):

Converting an IPv4 address to a number is deceptively complex. The reference function is [`inet_aton`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_aton) which does all the conversions correctly. You can also do this in Ruby to explore the different formats:

```
require 'socket'

addrs = %w[
  1.2.3.4
  1.2.3
  1.2
  1
]

addrs.each do |addr|
  puts '%12s -> %08x' % [
    addr,
    Socket.sockaddr_in(0, addr)[4,4].unpack('L>')[0]
  ]
end
```

This yields the following output:

```
 1.2.3.4 -> 01020304
   1.2.3 -> 01020003
     1.2 -> 01000002
       1 -> 00000001
```

The case of `1.2.3` and `1.2` is perhaps surprising. The last value is presumed to be a 16-bit value and 24-bit value respectively. These are all valid IPv4 addresses, though.

If you're writing your own, be sure to handle those strange edge-cases.

Comment: If writing your own be sure to check to see if the existing, well-tested, classes don't already do what's needed.

Answer (score 2):

The `IPAddr` class already handles that

```rb
IPAddr.new(631271850, Socket::AF_INET).to_s
# "37.160.113.170"
IPAddr.new("37.160.113.170").to_i
# 631271850
```